# 501 error code in cordova paytm payment gateway plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I implemented paytm-cordova-plugin for payment gateway in my app. Paytm account is at test mode. But it shows 501 error response code. The code implemented by me is attach in image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiVMN.png):

Answer (score 0):

Request you to use the correct param names as described in the All-in-One SDK integration document on paytm developer. For example the different parameters for the transaction are

```
mid : "<Merchant ID>",
orderId: "<Order ID>",
txnToken: "<Transaction Token generated by Initiate Transaction API from your backend>", 
amount: "<Amount>", 
isStaging: "<Environment(true/false)>", 
callbackUrl: "<Callback URL>
```

The callbackURL also need to be corrected. It should be https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<order_id> for staging environment.